# Issue with property place holder

Tags: properties, mule, anypoint-studio, property-placeholder

I have downloaded secure property place holder and secure encryption modules. But when i tried to open properties file by right clicking, i'm not getting **mule property editor** option to encrypt the properties inside.

can anybody assist me please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this article, you got to install Anypointstudio plugin to have Property Editor GUI.
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/installing-anypoint-enterprise-security

Depending on the Mule Runtime, select the appropriate plugin link for your case -https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/anypoint-enterprise-security-release-notes